# Закруглённые углы и тени в IE-8 и ниже

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Закруглённые углы и тени в версиях IE-8 и ниже не работают. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Советую почитать про css-спрайты (ссылку не дам, так как материалов по этой теме много) и заверстать сайт, используя png-24 в background-image для отрисовки уголков и теней. IE6 такой подход не поддерживает, поэтому для него можно написать css-хак, выводящий сообщение типа "на кофемолках сайт не работает, обновите кофемолку". Таким образом, если все правильно сверстать, сайт будет одинаково выглядеть во всех браузерах, не требуя включенного javascript'а.
Что же до IE6, то этого динозавра уже давно пора сливать в утиль, а скоро придет очередь и IE7. CSS3 можно будет вовсю использовать только тогда, когда "отвалится" IE8. А до этого момента CSS3 - просто украшение сайта для понимающих его браузеров.

Все, написанное выше - глубокое ИМХО и не претендует на открытие холивара.

Answer (score 2):

ссылки по теме:

- http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-shadow - на данном сайте можно смотреть, какие CSS свойства поддерживаются какими браузерамии

Что касается советов, которые предлагают. Считаю, что навешивать кучу яваскриптов ради закругленных углов - это неправильный подход.
Закругленные углы можно сделать, например, с помощью картинки. Градиент тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Использование rgba конечно хорошо, но не все так просто для все того же IE6-8 нужно добавить костылики

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    *background:transparent;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66000000,endColorstr=#66000000);
    *zoom: 1;
```

только так будет работать нормально, а что касается уголков и тенешек, то их нужно делать картинками. Самый простой способ (для новичка будет хороший опыт) это сделать 4 блока с позицией absolute и фиксированным размером и расскидать их по углам:

```
.corTopLeft{position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
```

Заодно и со спрайтами потренируетесь.

Answer (score 1):

ie 6,7,8 не поддерживают css3, но есть такое решение как [cssPIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Для IE подойдёт ещё modernizer.js

Answer (score 1):

Ищите в нете jQuery corners, jQuery border-radius и костыль прозрачности для png. Тут вроде были они все, плюс по-русски описано, что да как: [Shublog](Shublog.ru).

Если хотите полупрозрачный цвет бэкграунда, то можно обойтись без пнг-шек: в стилях пишете

```
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
```

это будет заливка блока, например, чёрным цветом с непрозрачностью 30%, т.е. первые 3 параметра-цвета: Красный, Зелёный, Синий, 4 параметр - альфа канал, по-нашенски, непрозрачность.